# How can I inject an already existing object into the object graph in Dagger 2?

Tags: java, dagger-2

I'm writing a web application with a framework that calls the `run()` method of my `Application` class and passes in an object of type `Environment`.

Other objects I'm writing depend on this `Environment` class, as they need to call its `register()` and `metrics()` methods.

The problem is that I create the object graph in the `main()` function of my application, like this:

```
public class MainApplication extends Application<MainConfiguration> {

private final ConnectionPool sharedPool;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
MainApplication mainApplication = DaggerMainApplicationComponent.create()
    .createApplication();

mainApplication.run(args);
}

@Inject public MainApplication(ConnectionPool connectionPool) {
super();
sharedPool = connectionPool;
}

@Override
public void run(MainConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    // Here is where I have access to the environment variable
}
```

So, by the time `MainApplication` is constructed by Dagger, the `environment` variable is not ready. It is only when `run()` is called that it is available.

Is there a way to inject this variable into the object graph at that point?

Comment: @BindsInstance or module constructor parameter

Comment: I added code to make my question clearer.

Comment: Oh. Personally I just create a singleton __Holder object and then set it when it's available. BackstackHolder, RealmHolder...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of question has already had some traction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049807/lazy-injection-with-dagger-2-on-android#34056809) but to answer your specific case and to elaborate on [EpicPandaForce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2413303/epicpandaforce)'s comment you can easily escape a small dependency cycle by creating a holder class:

```
class EnvironmentHolder {

    private Environment environment;

    @Nullable
    Environment get() {
        return environment;
    }

    void set(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }
}
```

And making the former dependencies of `Environment` dependencies of `EnvironmentHolder` instead:

```
class DependsOnEnvironment {

    private final EnvironmentHolder environmentHolder;

    @Inject
    DependsOnEnvironment(EnvironmentHolder environmentHolder) {
        this.environmentHolder = environmentHolder;
    }

    public void doSomethingWithMetrics() {
        Environment environment = environmentHolder.get();
        if (environment == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Environment object should be available at the injection time of this class");
        }

        Metrics metrics = environment.metrics();
        //etc.
    }
}
```

If you find yourself using this often it may be a sign that you need a custom scope instead.